# oimodeler python package - example scripts

Tags: python

I installed this package:

https://github.com/oimodeler/oimodeler

and I am trying to oimodeler-main/examples/Other/createModelChromatic.py

I obtained an error:

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'asscalar'
```

I did not find asscalar in any scripts in oimodeler directory. What does the error cause, please?

I get the same error after:

```
import oimodeler as oim
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the function asscalar has been [deprecated since Numpy version 1.16](https://numpy.org/doc/1.21/reference/generated/numpy.asscalar.html). You can downgrade your Numpy version but ideally the developers of the package should update their code.